# Retrieve the list of project active editors

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

This is related to eclipse plugin development.
Is there a way to retrieve the list of all active editors of an IResource of type project??
I am looking for a way to pro grammatically close all open editors related to one project that is being deleted.

thanks so much for any help. I am really stuck with this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The editors should already be closing themselves in reaction to the project deletion unless they're Dirty.  It's possible that only the active editor has the ability to ask you what to do with its contents, but trying to switch to any other editor that was open in that project should cause it to close.